# Mercedes A35 AMG 2022, short circuit/won't start/no comms with any vehicle modules

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module, mercedes-benz, fuse, a35

I need some help or direction. I recently purchased a salvage a35 which had undercarriage damage. On inspection it appears the wiring cable underneath the vehicle had been destroyed, chafing the wires which I suspect caused a short circuit as they were exposed and were touching the undertray/gearbox pan.

I have replaced these wires and we’ve got power to the vehicle including ignition. Although the vehicle does not start or attempt to start. Having a look at the diagnostic machine it appears I’m getting no communication with any of the vehicles modules, nothing seems to work. Before I go ahead and look to get a new ECU, I would be grateful if anyone could assist and maybe point me in the right direction as to what to look for or test.

Also was wondering if the ECU has blown, would this cause me to get no communication with the rest of the vehicles modules such as the TCM/BCM/ECU/4 MATIC MODULE, SUSPENSION MODULE etc

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is your diagnostic machine communicating with the ECU? Have you checked fuses to ensure the modules are getting powered up?

Comment: Hi Paulster2, many thanks for getting back to me. I have checked the fuses in the engine bay, all fuses appear to be okay. Unfortunately, I’m not best with electrics so unsure how to test the relays. In terms of communication with ECU. I am able to get power to the vehicle along with ignition. However once plugged in I get no communication from most of the modules in the vehicle. It does read a few modules such as ambient lighting etc but majority of the modules come as as ‘not equipped’ on my diagnostic machine.

Comment: That sounds more like a shortcoming of your diagnostics machine, not your car (at least at this point).

Comment: I will try another diagnostic machine, however once the vehicle has power and ignition there are a number of systems which don’t appear to work at all for instance the front headlights, the steering wheel controls etc. Which leads me to believe there is definitely an issue with the systems communicating or either the modules are just blown. If the ECU was at fault would this cause the other modules in the car to not work? I don’t really want to plow money into the car without knowing the engine and gearbox are okay, so my main aim is to get the vehicle up and running.

Comment: You stated there are (was) issues with the wiring harness. You sure this isn't the cause of things not working?

Comment: I will have another check at the wiring just to rule this out, and see if I’ve maybe missed something but as far as I’m aware I have rectified the damaged wiring. I will also double check all fuses etc. The vehicle has no damage to the engine, so I’m hoping the engine is fine, however I do have a nasty dent in the transmission oil pan but does not look as though I’ve lost any fluids. If anyone can recommend a Mercedes specialist/auto electrician who can figure out what’s wrong please let me know. I’m based in the north west.

Comment: A salvage vehicle, damaged wiring, symptoms of zero communication to a reader/scantool may not be enough to diagnose without advanced troubleshooting, with or without better scantools. Scantools may not be helpful if electrical and/or electronics are damaged/burned out/short circuited. At the least, service manuals are needed whether as diyer or experienced mechanic/tech familiar with electrical/electronic systems. Plus, factory antitheft/engine immobilizer systems that aren't diy friendly. Your choices are; M-B dealer, M-B repair shops specializing in M-Bs, indy M-B mobile tech.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every circuit on this car has fuses, if they are in fact all good then check your voltages at data link connector(dlc).  Pin 16 at DLC is your battery power, pin 4 & 5 your grounds, pin 6 and 14 your communication to gateway module which has access to all communication networks (CAN and Flex-ray).  A shorted wire on a bus will inhibit communication to any module on the bus.